# How to sort column by absolute value in SQL Server or Microsoft Access?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sorting

The values in a column has both negative and positive integers. I want to sort the column by its **absolute** value. How do I do this preferably in Access or in SQL? Thanks.

Comment: `... order by abs(yourfield)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MSSQL:

Use the `ABS()` function on the column you want to sort. ie:

`SELECT a, ABS(b)
FROM tbl
ORDER BY ABS(b)`

Answer (score 3):

```
select col1, Abs(col2) from table Order by 2;
```

Order by 2, takes 2nd column in the select statement, you can specify any number representing the sequence in the select

EDIT:
It's not a recommended practice, because:

1. It's not obvious/explicit
2. If the column order changes, the query is still valid so you risk ordering by something you didn't intend

One other way could be to use Column Alias: Something like:

```
select Abs(col1) as ABSID, * from Table order by ABSID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting has two types,Ascending and Descending. Sql provides the Function(order by) asc for ascending and desc for descending...

For Example: A table has list of values such as,
Employee_ID
01
02
06
08
04

The values can be sorted in ascending order as,

> Select Employee_ID FROM tablename order by Employee_ID ASC

This lists the values in ascending order such as,
Employee_ID
01
02
04
06
08

The values can be sorted in descending order as,

> Select Employee_ID FROM tablename order by Employee_ID DESC

This lists the values in descending order such as,
Employee_ID
08
06
04
02
01

Hope, You got your answer.Revert back for more clarifications..

Comment: where does this answer address the "absolute value" referred to in the question?